# Express pass req.body data into the Stripe route to pay

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

In my express application I have route that gets a cake price from the client side in the req.body

```js
app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
      let price = req.body[0].price * 1000;
      console.log(`Cake price is: £${price}`);
    });
```

This works fine and logs the price in the console

I have another route that I would like to pass this variable price from the req.body to Stripe and charge the customer.

```js
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "gbp",
          unit_amount: req.body[0].price,
          product_data: {
            name: "CakeItOrLeaveIt",
            // description: "", cake it or leave it description
            // images: [], cake it or leave it logo
          },
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: `http://localhost:4242/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:4242/cancel.html`,
  });
  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

When I pass the req.body[0].price into my Stripe route I get the below error.

> unit_amount: req.body[0].price, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to send the price data in request body in order for it to use the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending the price through to `/create-checkout-session` route on the client-side? What might be occurring is that you passing the price to the `/data` route on the client-side, but you aren't passing the price to the `/create-checkout-session`. It's hard to tell without seeing how you send your data to your API.

If you wanted to use one route - for instance the `/data` route you could transfer the `/create-checkout-session` into a function and call that function in the `/data` route and pass the price as a parameter to the `/create-checkout-session function`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was able to modify my code to req the cake price in the /create-checkout-session route

```js
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.body[0].price * 1000); //this works and gets the cake price

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "gbp",
          unit_amount: req.body[0].price * 1000, //this errors with Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')
          product_data: {
            name: "CakeItOrLeaveIt",
            // description: "", cake it or leave it description
            // images: [], cake it or leave it logo
          },
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: `http://localhost:4242/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:4242/cancel.html`,
  });
  
  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```